# Retrieve files from remote server using scp in crontab

Tags: bash, cron

I am trying to retrieve files from a remote server to my local PC using a cron job. However my script has to wait until the files are available on the remote server. From code pieces I gathered here and there, I came up with the code below

```
#!/bin/bash
year=$(date +%Y)
 month=$(date +%m)
day=$(date +%d)
hour="00"

ssh-keygen              # I suspect this line and the one below should be done once and not in the script.
ssh-copy-id _lms_2023
cd ${HOME}/ModelOutput_LMS/WRF_OUTPUT/tmp
cd ${HOME}/ModelOutput_LMS/WRF_OUTPUT/tmp

goto GOTO_1
if ssh lmshpc@41.203.191.69 "test -e /${HOME}/DA/OUTPUT/"$year$month$day$hour"/noda/graphics/*.png"; then
scp lmshpc@41.203.191.69:${HOME}/DA/OUTPUT/"$year$month$day$hour"/noda/graphics/*.png .

 if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  exit
 fi

else
 sleep 30
   GOTO_1
fi
```

I want the script to keep checking until the files are available and downloaded. The above script gives the errors below.
Any assistance will be appreciated.

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: Could not resolve hostname xxxxxxxxxx: Name or service not known

./cplocalfromRemote2.sh: line 14: goto: command not found

host's password:
```

Comment: `ssh-copy-id` thinks `_lms_2023` is the name of a host but it can't resolve that string as an actual host ... is your host really named `_lms_2023`?  and if so, why do the follow-on `ssh/scp` commands reference an ip of `41.203.191.69` (instead of a host named `_lms_2023`)? should the `ssh-copy-id` be referencing `41.203.191.69`?

Comment: in my environments `goto` is not a valid command or builtin; have you downloaded a package named `goto`? have you defined a script or function named `goto`? have you compiled a binary named `goto`? what does `type -a goto` show?

Comment: type -a goto gives bash: type: goto: not found

Comment: right, `goto` is an invalid command ... in `bash`; you'll need to recode to eliminate the `goto` call; a web search on `bash goto` should give you a few ideas to work with

Comment: `test -e prefix*` will do the right thing if _exactly one_ file matches `prefix*`; it will not at all do what you're hoping for if there's more than one match, and in not all cases will it do the right thing with zero matches (turn on the `nullglob` shell flag and then it becomes equivalent to `test -n "-e"`, which is true, if there are zero matches). [BashFAQ #4](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004) discusses some of the relevant concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way to do this is by using `rsync` instead of scp.

`rsync` checks/compares for new files automatically and copies only those files which are new/changed/modified or are not present in your destination location.

You can use rsync instead of scp in the script and set the script in cron to run every minute so that it gets the files which are newly added to the remote server.

1. The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
year=$(date +%Y)
 month=$(date +%m)
day=$(date +%d)
hour="00"

cd ${HOME}/ModelOutput_LMS/WRF_OUTPUT/tmp

sshpass -p'your_password' rsync -avh --progress lmshpc@41.203.191.69:${HOME}/DA/OUTPUT/"$year$month$day$hour"/noda/graphics/*.png .
```

2. Set up a cronjob that runs the script every minute.

`* * * * * /path/to/above/script.sh`

**EDIT:** I have changed the script to add host password for rsync in non-interactive mode.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello once again @mrrobot.viewsource. The script works ok, but then how does one go about the password, because it asks for the password. I am upvoting it any way, it works fine.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba Thanks for the upvote. You can specify password in the script using `sshpass`. I have edited the script to add password for rsync in non-interactive mode.

Comment: Thanks I found the way of logging in without it asking for passwd.